# How a loop works in struts application?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, jstl

Hi I'm developing a struts 2 application and to the jsp im getting the list of objects.
I want to do some thing like this  using s tag library.I can get member name using get  `<s:property value="#member.name"/>`

```
$(window).on('load', function () {


        <s:iterator value="members" var="member">
                    // GET MEMBER NAME & SEND TO POPULATE()
                populate(name);       
        </s:iterator> 


        });

        function populate(name){
            alert(name);                
        }
```

How can I send the **#member.name** of each member in members list to the **populate** function? Help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the property using `property` tag then you should pass it to the JS function as parameter. For example

```
populate('<s:property value="#member.name"/>');
```